# Content Blocks in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Is it possible to create small blocks of editable content on certain pages of a wordpress install?

I am thinking along the lines of little boxes that contain specific information that can be edited through the admin dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure it's possible, but you'd probably have to look in to the [WordPress plugin API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API) to hook in to the proper places and save it to the DB. Also check out [jQuery's inlne editor](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable) plugin.